# Place images into photoshop without confirmation prompt?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I drag and drop like 50 images into some opened psd.

To complete this i have to confirm a transformation 50 times (press enter or click the checkmark).

Any way to skip this step and make it apply them as if you didn't make any changes to the transformation?

The "resize image during place" found in general does something else even though its name suggests it does what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack`

One dialog to set.. then sit back and let Photoshop work.

This will open a new document and place all the images as layers... but you can then easily move the layers to another document if needed when the operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Goog working fo me
Preferences > General > Skip Transform when Placing
[image]

Comment: Not sure why this one is downvoted, this is exactly what the question asked for. Drag and drop, no transformation to confirm. The accepted answer is a workaround but not the best answer.